# Create csv file from array of data in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, csv

I want to write data from sql file to csv file. I have collected all data from sql file in an array and using for loop i am appending and writing data to .csv file. but it seems that it shows data in one line only it does not go to new line to create new row.
I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085206/iphone-write-csv-file-in-sandbox) for reference.
This is my code :

```
-(NSString *)dataFilePath { 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.csv"];
}

- (IBAction)saveAsFileAction:(id)sender {    
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: [self dataFilePath] contents:nil attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"Route creato");        
    }

    NSString *writeString;    
    for (int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++) {        
        writeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %0.2f,",[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]dates],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] time],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] category],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]place],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] amount]];        
        NSLog(@"writeString :%@",writeString);        
        NSFileHandle *handle;
        handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: [self dataFilePath] ]; 
        //say to handle where's the file fo write
        [handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]]; 
        //position handle cursor to the end of file
        [handle writeData:[writeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];      
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This only writes one line because you rewrite the file every time you go through your loop. It is best to not `writeData` on the file until the loop has completed. I would also use an NSMutableString like this:

```
- (IBAction)saveAsFileAction:(id)sender {

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath: [self dataFilePath] contents:nil attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"Route creato");
    }

    NSMutableString *writeString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0]; //don't worry about the capacity, it will expand as necessary

    for (int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++) {
        writeString = [writeString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %0.2f, \n",[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]dates],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] time],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] category],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]place],[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] amount]]]; //the \n will put a newline in
      }
    }

    //Moved this stuff out of the loop so that you write the complete string once and only once.
    NSLog(@"writeString :%@",writeString);

    NSFileHandle *handle;
    handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: [self dataFilePath] ]; 
    //say to handle where's the file fo write
    [handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]]; 
    //position handle cursor to the end of file
    [handle writeData:[writeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Comment: hey do you know how to retrive back the same data from csv file? @Prernachavan

Comment: writeString = [writeString appendString: won't pass compilation as writeString returns void. Besides, it's generally a bad idea to put all file content in memory before dumping as it can easily get blown.

Comment: You already use `NSMutableString`, then why write `writeString = [writeString appendString....` It's defeating the purposer of `NSMutableString`. Just remove the `writeString =`

Answer (score 5):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *root = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customers.csv"];

    NSString *temp;

    temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrCustomersName objectAtIndex:0]];

    for (int i = 1; i < [arrCustomersName count]; i++) {

        temp = [temp stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@", [arrCustomersName objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [temp writeToFile:root atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it's working for me ,

If any one want to create .csv file in **swift 3**

```
   // MARK: CSV file creating
    func creatCSV() -> Void {

    let fileName = "Tasks.csv"

    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    var csvText = "Date,Task Name,Time Started,Time Ended\n"

    for task in taskArr {
        let newLine = "\(task.date),\(task.name),\(task.startTime),\(task.endTime)\n"
        csvText.append(newLine)
    }

    do {
        try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file")
        print("\(error)")
    }
    print(path ?? "not found")
   }
  }
```

For more details you can refer [Detail Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42898831/4527240)

Hopes this will help to some one .

Answer (score 1):

```
 // For CSV File :
       NSMutableString *stringToWrite = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Name,Last Name,Full Name,Phone Number, Email,Job, organizationName,Note\n\n"]];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      for(int i = 0 ;i<[Contact count];i++)     {
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"firstName"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lastName"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[Contact valueForKey:@"userName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"emailAddress"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"jobTitle"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[Contact  objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"organizationName"] ]];
           [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[[Contact objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"note"] ]];
      }
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
           NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
           NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
           NSString *strBackupFileLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentDirectory,@"ContactList.csv"];
           [stringToWrite writeToFile:strBackupFileLocation atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
      });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but an answer is better with some explanation than just a whole block of code

Comment: code works perfectly! thank you for your answer and your time! -rrh