# How to convert Realm Database to CSV file format indirectly in iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

Direct conversion from realm database to CSV file format is not available in iOS. So is there any way to indirectly convert to CSV? Can I convert realm database to JSON or any comparable format and then convert from that format to CSV?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? I don't think there are any 3rd party libraries for that, since it doesn't make any sense. Realm is a cross-platform solution, so there's no need to convert its data to a different format, especially when that format was not designed to store such complex data that a Realm database can store.

Comment: @DávidPásztor : I want to store the data from beacon to Realm Database and than convert to CSV format and than upload it to the web service.....And direct conversion is not available for iOS so...

Comment: Why don't you use a Realm Object Server for storing the data on the backend side? There's no one-to-one relation between Realm data and CSV format, so you'd have to write the conversion logic yourself anyways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to ultimately create a CSV from data [go through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119035/create-csv-file-from-array-of-data-in-ios).
loop it over your data and add it to the csv fie.

Comment: Yah, I thought of this but this was my last option and I guess I've to go with iterating data and creating CSV file.....Thank You!!