# Is there a way to export realm database to CSV/JSON?

Tags: android, database, realm

I want to export my realm database to CSV/JSON in Android. Is there some in-build method in the realm database which can do this?

There is a iOS way of converting realm to CSV [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119035/create-csv-file-from-array-of-data-in-ios). I want a similar method in Android.

Comment: Java or Kotlin? Anyways, no official api for that : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2880

Comment: Java/kotlin anything will work.

Comment: so I figured out that I am not sure how you would implement it because there are fields like `RealmList<OtherRealmModel>` which don't really translate into CSV

Answer (score 2):

I was able to cobble together the following solution in my project:

```
// Grab all data from the DB in question (TaskDB):

RealmResults<TaskDB> resultsDB = realm.where(TaskDB.class).findAll();

// Here we need to put in header fields
String dataP = null;
String header = DataExport.grabHeader(realm, "TaskDB");

// We write the header to file
savBak(header);

// Now we write all the data corresponding to the fields grabbed above:
for (TaskDB taskitems: resultsDB) {
    dataP = taskitems.toString();

    // We process the data obtained and add commas and formatting:
    dataP = dataProcess(dataP);

    // Workaround to remove the last comma from final string
    int total = dataP.length() - 1;
    dataP =  dataP.substring(0,total);

    // We write the data to file
    savBak(dataP);
}
```

I will explain what it is doing as best I can and include all corresponding code(all in reference to the first code block).

The first I did is grab the header using the following method I wrote in a separate class (DataExport.grabHeader). It takes 2 arguments: the realm object in question and the DB object model name:

```
public static String grabHeader(Realm realm, String model){

    final RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
    final RealmObjectSchema testSchema = schema.get(model);
    final String header = testSchema.getFieldNames().toString();

    String dataProcessed = new String();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(header);

    while(m.find()) {

        dataProcessed += m.group(1).trim().replaceAll("\\p{Z}","");
    }

    return dataProcessed;
```

Within grabHeader, I apply some regex magic and spit out a string that will be used as the header with the appropriate commas in place (String dataProcessed).
In this scenario, after I obtained the data needed, I used another method (savBak) to write the information to a file which takes 1 string argument:

```
    @Override
    public void savBak(String data){
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.write("\n".getBytes());

            Log.d("tester", "saved to: " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The "savBak" method writes the information to a FILE_NAME specified in a variable and we have our header information. After the header is written, we do the basically the same process with the DB using a forloop but I also had to include 2 lines to remove the trailing comma after the line was processed. Each line is appended to the file and viola, CSV formatted goodness.

From here, you can use other existing methods of converting CSV to JSON and whatever else as well as putting the information back into realm via JSON. When it comes to more advanced elements like primary keys and such, I am not sure but  it worked for my particular project needs.

Please excuse any "bad code" practice as I'm new to Java/Android in general coming from a "barely intermediate" Python background so hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I got a reply from Realm support via email.

Unfortunately, we do not have this feature yet.  You can see it tracked here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2880

You could use a dynamic API and write a script yourself to perform a similar feature.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version of vRasheed's answer used in my app

```
fun exporttoCsv(context: Context?, realm: Realm) {
    val FILE_NAME = "wordpairs.csv"
    // Grab all data from the DB in question (WordPairs):
    val resultsDB = realm.where(WordPairs::class.java).findAll()

    // Here we need to put in header fields
    var dataP: String?
    val header = AdvancedSettingsDataImportExportHelper.grabHeader(realm, "WordPairs")

    // We write the header to file
    AdvancedSettingsDataImportExportHelper.savBak(context!!, header, FILE_NAME)

    // Now we write all the data corresponding to the fields grabbed above:
    //
    val count = resultsDB.size
    if (count != 0) {
        var irrh = 0
        while (irrh < count) {
            val taskitems = resultsDB[irrh]!!
            //
            dataP = taskitems.toString()
            // We process the data obtained and add commas and formatting:
            dataP = AdvancedSettingsDataImportExportHelper.dataProcess(dataP)
            // Workaround to remove the last comma from final string
            val total = dataP.length - 1
            dataP = dataP.substring(0, total)

            // Workaround to remove the last line feed from final row
            // We write the data to file
            if (irrh == count - 1) {
                AdvancedSettingsDataImportExportHelper.savBak(
                    context,
                    dataP,
                    FILE_NAME,
                    true
                )
            } else {
                AdvancedSettingsDataImportExportHelper.savBak(
                    context,
                    dataP,
                    FILE_NAME,
                    false
                )
            }
            irrh++
        }
    }
}

/**
 * prepares the realm table header for export
 *
 * @param realm realm obtained from the activity by Realm#getDefaultInstance
 * @param model string containing the name of the realm class to export
 * @return string header for export
 * @see Realm.getSchema
 * @see RealmSchema.get
 * @see RealmObjectSchema.getFieldNames
 * @see [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
 *
 * @see [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)
 */
fun grabHeader(realm: Realm, model: String): String {
    val schema = realm.schema
    //
    val testSchema = schema[model]!!
    //
    val header = testSchema.fieldNames.toString()
    val dataProcessed = StringBuilder("")
    //
    val p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)]")
    val m = p.matcher(header)
    //
    while (m.find()) {
        // String   Matcher#group(int group)
        // Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous
        // match operation.
        // String#trim()
        // Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
        // String   String#replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
        // Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression
        // with the given replacement.
        // \Z   The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any
        // toglie l'ultimo carattere ?
        dataProcessed.append(Objects.requireNonNull(m.group(1)).trim { it <= ' ' }
            .replace("\\p{Z}".toRegex(), ""))
    }
    return dataProcessed.toString()
}

//
/**
 * process the data corresponding to the fields of the table to export and add commas and formatting
 *
 * @param dataP string containing data to be processed
 * @return string processed data
 * @see [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
 *
 * @see [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)
 */
fun dataProcess(dataP: String?): String {
    // We process the data obtained and add commas and formatting:
    val dataProcessed = StringBuilder("")
    //
    val p = Pattern.compile(":(.*?)\\}")
    val m = p.matcher(dataP!!)
    //
    while (m.find()) {
        // String   Matcher#group(int group)
        // Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous
        // match operation.
        // String#trim()
        // Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
        // String   String#replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
        // Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression
        // with the given replacement.
        // searches for characters between : and }
        dataProcessed.append(Objects.requireNonNull(m.group(1)).trim { it <= ' ' })
        dataProcessed.append(",")
    }
    return dataProcessed.toString()
}

//
/**
 * writes data to the output file
 *
 *
 * if it is the last line to write, it does not add the newline character
 *
 * @param data string data to be recorded
 * @param fileName string name of the output file
 * @param isLastRow boolean true if it is the last line to write
 */
fun savBak(context: Context, data: String, fileName: String?, isLastRow: Boolean?) {
    var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
    try {
        // fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
        // fos = null
        fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND)
        fos.write(data.toByteArray())
        if (!isLastRow!!) fos.write("\n".toByteArray())
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```